# copying a file from remote node to my own system

Tags: linux, login, scp

I am using the following command to move a file (sender.log) which is on a remote node to my own PC:

`scp linux-Vostro-1014@example.com:sender.log /root/Desktop`

When I use this command it asks:

`linux-Vostro-1014@example's password:`

What should I enter here? When I enter my system password, the output is

`Permission denied (publickey,password)`

How do I resolve this, what should I be entering?

Answer (score 1):

Without SSH keys set up between you and the server, or any other mechanism of authentication, the usual fallback is a password, and in this case, it's asking for the SSH password of user `linux-Vostro-1014` on the remote system, as that is the username you're specifying with that command (everything before the @). This password may or may not be the same as your local password.

Whoever has provided you with access to the remote system should be able to retrieve your login credentials for you, be it via key or password.

As noted by another user, you can try a verbose command to see exactly which login methods are tried:

```
scp -v linux-Vostro-1014@example.com:sender.log /root/Desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

You would enter the password that is being prompted for.

(I see you  have a "/" afte the : at ...bbn.com:sender.log and wonder if that is an issue for you)

You could may find that the user (linux-Vostro-1014) does not exist on the remote end - indeed I suspect that your form of command is wrong, and this should be your username.    [ It could also be that ssh is configured not to accept logins for that username ]

To debug the problem, first make sure you can log in with SSH.  If you can't, try adding verbose logging (-v) and provide the results of the log.